# Windows Store App C# XAML: NavigationHelper LoadState/SaveState Radio Button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

How to save radio button selection when navigating the back and forward?

For textbox, I know it's something like this:

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PageState != null)
        {
            this.text5_input.Text = e.PageState["txtContents"] as string;

        }
    }


 private void navigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PageState["txtContents"] = this.text5_input.Text;
    }
```

However when we use the similar code for radio buttons, an error pops up saying cannot convert string(e.PageState) to bool(radio button).

How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use RadioButtonInstance.IsChecked.ToString and to recover the data use bool.Parse((bool)e.PageState["rbState"])

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PageState != null)
    {
        this.text5_input.Text = e.PageState["txtContents"] as string;
        this.RadioButtonInstance.IsChecked = (bool)e.PageState["rbState"];
    }
}

private void navigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
{
    e.PageState["txtContents"] = this.text5_input.Text;
    e.PageState["rbState"] = this.RadioButtonInstance.IsChecked;
}
```

In theory this is for bool, can you try?

Comment: Hi, sorry I took so long to reply back. The answer you have given me however does not work, and I am still getting converting errors. Can you help me out? I can post my full code to you if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, can I send you my task via email/dropbox instead?

Comment: Hi sir, I haven't got a reply from you since yesterday. Can I kindly ask whether it is still possible to request help from you?

Comment: You can paste the code here http://pastebin.com/ and tell me when you added I can take a look right now

Comment: I haven't edited anything on the loadstate and savestate http://pastebin.com/tHVbiS9R

Comment: take a look to the addition to the answer

Comment: Two errors:

`if (e.PageState = null)` The property or indexer FYPPrototype1.Common.LoadStateEventArgs.PageState cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible and

Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object> to 'bool'